# Error al ingresar al sistema

Tags: php, java, mysql

```html
<form class="user" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block submit-btn" value="Login">
                    
                    
                    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.user').on("click",".submit-btn",function()
{
    var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pass= document.getElementById('pass').value;

    var dataen = 'email='+email
                +'&pass='+pass;
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'sesion.php',
        data:dataen,

        success:function(resp_gene)
        {
            $("#msj-error").html(resp_gene);
            $("#msj-error").show();
            setTimeout("$('#msj-error').fadeOut('slow');",3000);

        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Este pedazo de codigo es mi login, ese script recibe los valores y los manda al archivo sesion.php que les anexo enseguida, cuando lo corro me parece que tengo un error en la linea 28 que es esta: if ($email==$row['email']) {. No me permite loguearme, espero me ayuden a resolver esta duda que ya me desesperó.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    `

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$conexion = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conexion->connect_error){
    die ("LA CONEXION FALLÓ: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$email = $_POST['email']; 
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

echo "<script> alert('".$email."'); </script>";
echo "<script> alert('".$pass."'); </script>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarioss WHERE correo ='$email'";

$result = $conexion->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    }

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($email==$row['email']) {

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;


    echo "<br><br><a href=index2.php></a>";
    header('Location: http://localhost/control_admin/index2.php');
} else {

    echo "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
    echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Volver a intentarlo</a>";
}

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>`
```

Comment: ¿Por qué te parece que tienes un error en esa línea? ¿Sale algo en pantalla? ¿Sale algo en los logs?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\control_admin\sesion.php on line 28
Correo o contraseña incorrectos
Volver a intentarlo

Comment: Cuando le doy login me sale ese error en pantalla

Comment: Deberías depurar el código para ver si `$row` realmente contiene lo que crees que contiene. El mensaje de error es bastante claro: `Undefined index`. El índice `email` no existe o es nulo, por eso la comparación falla. Estás tratando de acceder a un índice de un `array` que no existe o no está definido. Solo mostrando en pantalla lo que tiene `$row` podrás saber lo que sucede. Puedes usar [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php). Saludos

Comment: Otra cosa que debo hacerte notar, es que no estás usando [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), por lo tanto tu aplicación es suceptible a ataques tipo [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Te invito a que corrijas eso, ya que es una parte muy importante de la seguridad de tu sistema, además de ser una buena práctica. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no existe la key "email" y no estas validando que la consulta devuelva algo.

despues de

```
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
```

cambia lo siguiente:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        if(!isset($row['email'])){
             echo "mi tabla no tiene el campo email! ops!!!! :C";
             die;
        }


    if ($email===$row['email']) {

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;


        echo "<br><br><a href=index2.php></a>";
        header('Location: http://localhost/control_admin/index2.php');
    }


}else {
    echo "Correo o contraseña incorrectos";
    echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Volver a intentarlo</a>";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```